# I want the 'print("hello.")' function and 'while True: ~winclose()' to run simultaneously

Tags: python

```
import psutil
import win32gui
import time
import os,subprocess
import pyautogui



while True:
    for win in pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('notepad'):

        print(win)
        win.close()


    for win in pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('google'):

        print(win)
        win.close()

print("hello.")
```

Even though I created 'while True: ~ winclose()' in another .py and imported it, the 'print("hello.")' function does not work.

Comment: Did you notice that you have an infinite loop? If your *print(win)* code isn't revealing anything it's because *getWindowsWithTitle()* isn't returning anything

Comment: I want to print("hello.") active. not print(win)

Comment: *print("hello.")* will never be executed due to the infinite loop that precedes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a infinite loop and the `print("hello.")` is outside the loop, so it will never run.

Try something like this

```py
import psutil
import win32gui
import time
import os,subprocess
import pyautogui

while True:
    for win in pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('notepad'):
        print(win)
        win.close()

    for win in pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('google'):
        print(win)
        win.close()

    print("hello.")

    time.sleep(.5) # Optionally: Added delay of 0.5s
```

I think this is what you want

```py
import threading
import time
import pyautogui

def crawl_news():
    # Do what you want do do for NewS crawling
    print("Crawling news.s.s.s")

def check_windows():
    while True:
        notepad_open = len(pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('notepad')) > 0
        google_open = len(pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('google')) > 0

        if notepad_open:
            print("Notepad is open")

        if google_open:
            print("Google is open")

        time.sleep(1) # Dealy in between

newsProcess = threading.Thread(target=crawl_news)
windowProcess = threading.Thread(target=check_windows)

newsProcess.start()
windowProcess.start()

newsProcess.join()
windowProcess.join()
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I want is not 'print("hello")' to be repeated.

Comment: @레이첼유아 so when do you want it to print?

Comment: The original source code is news page crawling, not 'print("hello")'. I also want to check whether 'notepad' and 'google' are turned on while crawling the news page. Like ‘multi processing’

Comment: @레이첼유아 Not sure what you are saying, So please explain it more

Comment: @레이첼유아 I have updated my code, let me know if this is what you want or not

Comment: yes. i want it. thank you!

Comment: @레이첼유아 Welcome 